# Pip Install SHAP Failed in Pip Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pip, virtual-environment, shap

I am using the pip virtual environment on Python 3.6.3 on a Linux server.

I tried pip installing SHAP but encountered below error:

```
          Building wheel for shap (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Complete output from command XXXX/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aq97v0m2/shap/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-v9vyt50m --python-tag cp36:
      ERROR: running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap
      copying shap/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap
      copying shap/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap
      copying shap/datasets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/pytree.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/deep.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/sampling.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/mimic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/linear.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/gradient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/explainer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/kernel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      copying shap/explainers/tree.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers/other
      copying shap/explainers/other/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers/other
      copying shap/explainers/other/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers/other
      copying shap/explainers/other/coefficent.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/explainers/other
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/colors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/dependence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/summary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      copying shap/plots/force.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      copying shap/benchmark/plots.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      copying shap/benchmark/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      copying shap/benchmark/methods.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      copying shap/benchmark/scorers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      copying shap/benchmark/metrics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/benchmark
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots/resources
      copying shap/plots/resources/logoSmallGray.png -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots/resources
      copying shap/plots/resources/bundle.js -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/plots/resources
      running build_ext
      numpy.get_include() /usr/local/share/anaconda/anaconda3-5.0.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include
      building 'shap._cext' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap
      gcc -pthread -B /usr/local/share/anaconda/anaconda3-5.0.1/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/XXX/include -I/usr/local/share/anaconda/anaconda3-5.0.1/include/python3.6m -I/usr/local/share/anaconda/anaconda3-5.0.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c shap/_cext.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/shap/_cext.o
      gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for shap
  Running setup.py clean for shap
Failed to build shap
Installing collected packages: shap
  Running setup.py install for shap ... error
```

I browsed a few similar issues and tried installing SHAP by specifying package version, but haven't had any success.

Can you please advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OS? Full text of the error?

Comment: this is on Linux server and full error updated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The error that crashes your install is :

```
error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Can be fixe by installing g++ :

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

If a message displays like: Couldn't find package, then try the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: I actually don't have sudo right on this server. Any alternatives for this? Thanks!